# Flutter return json where id = [31,34]

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

When I click a button, I want to get a new list. And the example below
**i have this list :**

```
List users = [
  {
    "id": 31,
    "name": "John",
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Sami",
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Leon",
  }
];
```

**when search for id list like [31,34]**

i need return this result

```
List users = [
  {
    "id": 31,
    "name": "John",
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Leon",
  }
];
```

Comment: use `List.where` method then, something like: `users.where((e) => [31, 34].contains(e['id']).toList()` - of course instead of `[31, 34]` you can use any list of ids

Comment: first you have to get a list which contains ids of all the items;

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it out like this
`var newList = users.where((e) => e['id']==31 || e['id']==34).toList();`

Comment: I have a lot of id. I can't do it that way.

Comment: Check it with a list then and change the method a bit but first you need to have a `List` with the ids you want to search
`var newList = users.where((e) => idsToSearch.contains(e['id'])).toList();`

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
List users = [
  {
    "id": 31,
    "name": "John",
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Sami",
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Leon",
  }
];

List<searchIds> = [31, 23];

List<searchUsers> = [];

for (int i = 0; i < searchIds.length; i++) {
      searchUsers.add(users.where((x) => x["id"] == searchIds[i]).toList()[0]);
}
```